# Translation of sprintf

Tags: wordpress, poedit

Poedit recognizes and translates this part and I save it but it isn't translated on theme. How can I do it correctly?

```
   'description' =>sprintf(__("Thank you for being part of this! We've spent almost 6 months building ThemeIsle without really knowing if anyone will ever use a theme or not, so we're very grateful that you've decided to work with us. Wanna <a href=http://themeisle.com/contact/' target='_blank'>say hi</a>?
<br/><br/><a href='http://themeisle.com/demo/?theme' target='_blank' />View Theme Demo</a> | <a href='http://themeisle.com/forums/forum/' target='_blank'>Get theme support</a><br/><br/><a href='http://themeisle.com/documentation' target='_blank'>Documentation</a>"), 'theme'),
                 'priority' => 30,
```

Answer (score 0):

[My psychic powers](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/02/17/74812.aspx#74862) tell me that this snippet of code lacking any context is part of a (static?) variable initialization executed *before you [loaded the translation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/load_theme_textdomain/)*.

PHP’s implementation of gettext doesn’t support going back in time. You have to load the domain before any calls to `__()` or friends.

Comment: Yeah this is a part of code that I have problem about  it. I translated all codes and I used "load theme textdomain " on function.php everything work well except this part.Thank you Mr Salvik.